# Custom Post Type Category Displaying ALL Sub Categories as well

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

So Ive created a CPT and added categories to it. I've assigned the individual posts to categories, including a parent category and sub categories.

The sub categories are filtering fine, but the parent  category is displaying the posts of all the child categories as well. In other words, I have 3 posts in the parent category, and then several posts in the sub categories.

This page - https://integrated.webpossible.net/treatment-area/ - should only be displaying the 3 sub categories - face treatments, body and skin - but it's showing all the posts within each of those categories.

When  I look at the category list on the back end, it only shows 3, but when I click on that number, it shows all posts versus just the 3 that  it should filter down to.

What's the deal?

Comment: Categories contain their sub-categories. If you think as categories as boxes, sub-categories are nested boxes, not connected boxes, so the behaviour you are seeing is expected, it is not a bug. An example might be a `colour` taxonomy with a `red` term, and a sub-term named `bright reds`. Red contains all bright reds, all bright reds are red, so if we list everything in red, we get the bright reds too, checking the red box is not necessary. That's why you are seeing this behaviour. Note though that this is a comment explaining the behaviour, not an answer to change the behaviour.

Comment: Also, there is no code to debug or fix in your question, use the edit link under the tags to update the question and include the relevant code

Comment: I have a strong suspicion that you do not have any code and are actually asking for help with a Divi page builder feature. If so then you need to ask their support, any answer you get here will be of limited use to you, and nobody will be able to help if you don't share this information. **Are you using a page builder to list those posts?** Or are you using PHP code?

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks Tom. That actually did answer the question. I just removed the parent category and we're all set now. However, another issue I'm running into is the CPT is displaying the h1 and entry content area in the source code even though I have that removed via Divi. Is there  a  way to remove that entry content from the source code? Example  page - https://integrated.webpossible.net/treatment-areas/skin/

Comment: You'll need help from other Divi users, that's not something I or others on this site can help you with. Divi and other 3rd party theme/plugins are off topic here